# How to link thumbnail to a video on a new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I click on a thumbnail,  I want to have another web page open up with the video of that thumbnail. How would I do that? Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is HTML 101 stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a style="
  background: url('*Thumbnail URL*');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 270px;
  width: 540px;"
href="*Video URL*"></a>
```

`*Thumbail URL*` < Insert the location of the thumbnail you want to use.

`*Video URL*` < Insert the location of the video you want to direct the user to.

Comment: I've added the necessary `url(' ')` syntax, and the `background-size: contain;` property which will make that background image reach the maximum size within that element while maintaining its aspect ratio and without cropping anything off.

Comment: I saw, thanks very much, you were very forgiving